# Registration in php, session start and redirection

Tags: php, session, registration

I have the following registration.php file:

```
<?php 
include_once("QueryNew.php"); 

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

$email=addslashes($_POST["email"]);
$password=addslashes($_POST["password"]);
$confirmpassword=addslashes($_POST["confirmpassword"]);
$uid=uniqid();

}

if (trim($email," ") == "" || trim($password," ") == "" && trim($confirmpassword," ") == ""){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='logintips.php?regErr=All fields are mandatory'</script>";
}

if (trim($password," ") != trim($confirmpassword," ")){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='logintips.php?regErr=Passwords didnot match'</script>";
}

if (trim($email," ") != "" || trim($password," ") != "" && trim($confirmpassword," ") != ""){

        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO user VALUES('".$uid."','".$email."','".$password."','',1,".CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.")";
        $qry = new QueryNew();
        $insert = $qry->executeSelect($insertQuery);

        $SELECT_STAR = "select uid, email, timezone from ";

        $selectQuery = $SELECT_STAR . "user" . " where email = '".$email."'";

        $qry = new QueryNew();
        $select = $qry->executeSelect($selectQuery);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
            $uidS = $row['uid'];
            $emailS = $row['email'];
        }

**//store $uidS and $emailS in a session variable and redirect to a (home) page**

}
?>
```

Once I am done with the insert and select queries, I want to create a session and redirect to someother page..

I tried session_start() as below:

```
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[uid] = $uidS;
        $_SESSION[email] = $emailS;

        echo $_SESSION[uid];
        echo $_SESSION[email];
```

Which gives an error:

```
**Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\website\try\MAIN\HOME\QueryNew.php:43) in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\try\MAIN\HOME\register.php on line 45**
```

If there is a better way than the above, please suggest.

Comment: Original error message is zillion times better than something like "the above isnt working.. says session already created"

Comment: may be session_start() already defined in file so try removing that line

Comment: @zerkms: edited the original post - added the actual error

Comment: somewhere you already start session

Comment: @MohitBumb: well.. thats why i have posted this question.. to find the answer somehow!

Comment: ok check answer and start session only when its not started

Comment: @Mohit Bumb: you're wrong. This error means literally what is written - headers already sent. It has nothing to do with session started twice

Comment: ok ok then try ob_start(); before session_start();

Answer (score 1):

Read your error message.

`QueryNew.php` is generating some output (at line `43`). You should not echo or print anything before you start your session. You could start the session **before** you include `QueryNew.php` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ob_start();

------------------
-----------
-------

ob_end_flush() ;
```

Comment: thanks.. but is there a way to "create a session with the db values and redirect to someother page (say home page)"

Comment: i checked that question.. there is only one <?php ?> tag in my complete file!

Comment: You can do this by calling ob_start() and ob_end_flush() in your script, or setting the output_buffering configuration directive on in your php.ini or server configuration files.

Comment: A good design won't need output buffers, if you come to using OB then you should consider a redesign of your architecture!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ob_start();
if(session_id()){
//Session is already started
}else{
session_start();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put **ob_start()** in top of the page will resolve this error